# fromPixel produces different tensor depending on platform

Tags: tensorflow.js

I am loading an image into a tensor using this code snippet

```js
var img = document.getElementById("myImage");  
var example =tf.fromPixels(img);
example = tf.image.resizeBilinear(example, [150, 150], align_corners=true);
example = example.toFloat().div(tf.scalar(255));
example = example.reshape([1, 150, 150, 3]); 
example.print()
```

When classifying the image with some model in tensorflow.js, I realized that I am getting slightly different softmax outputs, depending on where (e.g. my laptop vs my pixel 3 phone) I run it.

Debugging a bit further, I realized that the values in tensor I obtain from tf.fromPixels() are slightly different depending on the platform.

Is this to be expected ? Anyone has an idea why this is the case and what to be done to prevent it ?

Answer (score 3):

[`tf.fromPixels`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-core/blob/c6a71dbd2eda2fe8863b9995abd59437795a14cc/src/kernels/backend_cpu.ts#L134) makes use of the [HTMLCanvasElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement). browsers tend to use different image processing engines, etc. therefore, similar canvas elements can produce different values depending on the system.

more info:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28731789/5446300
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4310653/5446300
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26615864/5446300