# Inconsistent canvas.getimagedata() values returned on Chromium based browsers

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, chromium, getimagedata

**Edit: solution is *(weirdly)* to activate `willReadFrequently: true` on the canvas, Chromium & getImageData() will return consistent values, see answer below.**

I'm currently running a program that pick a pixel from a canvas where an image is previously loaded using `canvas.getImageData()` , analyse the RGB values from the pixel then run calculations based on blue and red values.

I encountered a weird behavior only on Chrome/Chromium/Edge browsers : the first time and image is loaded, the value returned for a specific pixel is `RGB(181,1,1)`, if i load the exact same image again in the canvas with `canvas.drawImage()` and pick the exact same pixel multiple times with `canvas.getImageData()` i now get `RGB(181,1,2)`.

**HTML:**

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

**JS:**

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d", {alpha: false,});
    
const IMG = new Image();
IMG.src = "myImage.jpg"

ctx.drawImage(IMG, 0, 0, 500, 500);
console.log("first image draw : " + ctx.getImageData(66, 27, 1, 1).data);

ctx.drawImage(IMG, 0, 0, 500, 500);
console.log("Second image draw : " + ctx.getImageData(66, 27, 1, 1).data);

ctx.drawImage(IMG, 0, 0, 500, 500);
console.log("Third image draw : " + ctx.getImageData(66, 27, 1, 1).data);

ctx.drawImage(IMG, 0, 0, 500, 500);
console.log("Fourth image draw : " + ctx.getImageData(66, 27, 1, 1).data);

ctx.drawImage(IMG, 0, 0, 500, 500);
console.log("fifth image draw : " + ctx.getImageData(66, 27, 1, 1).data);
```

Result on Chrome :

```
"first image draw : 181,1,1,255"
"Second image draw : 181,1,1,255"
"Third image draw : 181,1,2,255"
"Fourth image draw : 181,1,2,255"
"fifth image draw : 181,1,2,255"
```

Result on Firefox :

```
"first image draw : 181,1,2,255"
"Second image draw : 181,1,2,255"
"Third image draw : 181,1,2,255"
"Fourth image draw : 181,1,2,255"
"fifth image draw : 181,1,2,255"
```

This behaviour only happen on chromium based browsers, on webkit/firefox i get `RGB(181,1,2)` no matter what.

I recreated this behaviour on codepen : open it on chrome/firefox and see the difference :
https://codepen.io/sh4kman/pen/qBgaNbe

[Screenshot comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndOS4.png)

i tried :

1. Disabling antialiasing (context.imageSmoothingEnabled= false)
2. Clearing canvas (canvas.clearRect()) before/after every getImageData() call

I'm aware that different browser [can have different render/rounding colors for images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28731423/javascript-canvas-getimagedata-ie-vs-chrome), but here i have different value on the same browser, always following the same pattern

Comment: Maybe not related to your problem but you should add a Promise there to wait for `onload` because for me, sometimes the IMG is not loaded yet and all I get is a black screen.

Comment: Yes ! Didn't bother include it in the codepen but i'm using a load event in my real code. Still encounter this problem with .addEventlistener("load") though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot give an actual answer to this but experimenting with the `willReadFrequently`
attribute of the canvas as mentioned in the warning of the console
I get different results on Chromium.

> Canvas2D: Multiple readback operations using getImageData are faster with the `willReadFrequently` attribute set to true. See: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#concept-canvas-will-read-frequently

I forked the CodePen link and tried changing the values to `undefined` (default)
`false` and `true`.
All of them behave different from one another.

#### undefined

The default behavior
[image]

#### false

Consistent behavior with the 3rd value being `1`
[image]

#### true

Consistent behavior with the 3rd value being `2`
[image]

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/Danny2006/pen/vYbXJWR

Comment: I've come across this options but it never crossed my mind to test it because i'm just.. not reading Frequently the canvas ? It definitly fix it thanks !  
  
This is a weird one, to my understanding this option decide whether to store the canvas image on the GPU or on the CPU in case of frequent getImageData() use and for performance reasons. Looks like there's is definitly no reason not to enable it even if you are calling getDataImage() once ?

Comment: I can't really tell. But it's weird that `false` works different than `undefined`.